# I have an annoying c++ outstream bug

Tags: c++, file-io, iostream

This code reads the correct sets of x,y coordinate from txt file at C:\a\b.txt. I know ifstream is working, because I used cout to verify. It won't create a new file for me. Someone suggested using close(), and it create a file one time. Then I tried again, many times, and it won't create a file. I'm inputing: C:\a\c.txt

I don't think there's anything wrong with my code. Can anyone spot a problem, or suggest a solution?

```
#include "lib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
//....Point class and istream>> operator code

int main()
{
//....ifstream code

std::string filename;
cout << "Enter output filename: ";
std::getline(cin, filename);

ofstream ost(filename.c_str(), std::ofstream::out);
if (!ost.is_open()) cerr << "can't open output file: " << filename << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<points.size(); ++i)
        ost<<'('<<points[i].x<<','<<points[i].y<<')'<<endl;
        cout <<"got here 6"<<endl;

    ost.close();

    keep_window_open();

    return 0;

}
```

After the code runs the MS compiler gives this message in the output box:

```
project chap 10 ex 1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project chap 10 ex 1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\snxhk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project chap 10 ex 1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project chap 10 ex 1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project chap 10 ex 1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'project chap 10 ex 1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'project chap 10 ex 1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project chap 10 ex 1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project chap 10 ex 1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project chap 10 ex 1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project chap 10 ex 1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project chap 10 ex 1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project chap 10 ex 1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project chap 10 ex 1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project chap 10 ex 1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project chap 10 ex 1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project chap 10 ex 1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project chap 10 ex 1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project chap 10 ex 1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xacc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[6132] project chap 10 ex 1.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Those are just the debugging symbols.  It is telling you that it couldn't find debugging symbols for system libraries.

Comment: My question was: I don't think there's anything wrong with my code. Can anyone spot a problem, or suggest a solution?

Comment: Yes, the `for` loop is executed if there are problems opening the file.

Comment: The fact that *ifstream is working* seems quite useless, because you do not use any ifstream in your programm. Why did you think it was worth mentioning?

Comment: If you overload `operator>>` for `istream`, you should also overload `operator<<` for ostream in the point structure.

Comment: You should learn to use `{` and `}` after `if`, `for`, and `while` statements.  It will clear up your code and prevent many mistakes from occurring.

Comment: You write to `cerr` conditionally. Do you see the output of that code (i.e. is the condition for writing to cerr fulfilled)?

Comment: Looks like you may not be using a debugger.  Learn to use a debugger more effectively.

Comment: How are you *inputing: C:\a\c.txt*? What's the type and value of `filename`?

Comment: C:\a\b.txt Now it started working. I actually didn't write a lot this code, I grabbed other's code as attempts to fix my code. At any rate I now suspect it's the stupid Avast antivirus. It blocks everthing. I ran the program normally a few times, instead of in the "sandbox". First few times it still didn't work, and now it's working. Very strange. I wish I knew what's going on here.

Comment: At the top of visual studio is a drop-down that says "Release", click the drop down and select "Debug" then press F11 to start the program in the debugger and pause execution at the first line of main.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "lib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
//....Point class and istream>> operator code

int main()
{
    //....ifstream code
    ofstream ost(filename, std::ofstream::out); // filename is never initialized?
    if (ost.is_open()) 
    {
        for(int i=0; i<points.size(); ++i)
        {
            ost<<'('<<points[i].x<<','<<points[i].y<<')'<<endl;
        }
        cout <<"got here 6"<<endl;
        ost.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Unable to open file:  " << filename << endl;
    }

    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

With the code you have shown, the only problems (other than your horrible formatting) are that you never initialize `filename`, and you still attempt to write to the `ofstream` if it failed to open.

Comment: No I did initialize. I forgot to show that. It's not my formatting. As I said in earlier comments. I swiped all that ofstream code from other forums attempting to fix my initial problem. I was really not interested in formatting code that doesn't work and was a quick fix. I already seemed to have solved the problem. I think Avast is blocking me from opening files. I think.

Comment: Which BTW, I don't understand why code that no one else can find problem with, or find a solution for, and it turns out to be blocked by the virus software, is a -1 for my reputation.